# How can I pass the boolean value to the variable from Controller to view in CI

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need your help to pass a bool value of the variable in the view from the controller & get the output in view if $a ==true then Output:1. And if $a==false, than output:2.
For Eg:
My view is like:

```
if(!$a) { 
  echo "Hi";
} else{
  echo "Hello World";
}
```

How can I pass the $a bool value from controller to view ??

Comment: it's `!$a` , you can pass as `$data['a'] = TRUE` OR `$data['a'] = 1`, and pass `$data` in view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Controller Code:-**

```
    if($statement == true) {
           $data['output']="something will be generate here";      
       }     
    
       else if ($statement == false) {
           $data['output']="something else be generate here";      
       }     
       else {
           $data['output']="nothing";      
       }

$this->load->view('page', $data);
```

**In View:**

```
<?php

echo $output;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$a` is a checkbox then make value of checkbox as 1 then

```php
if ( $a==1 ){
  echo "Checked";
} else {
  echo "not checked";
}
```